# ln -s /path/to/ in windows

Tags: linux, windows, openmrs

I am implementing openmrs application as part of it's installation, they have given one command to run in the command prompt in linux, but i am using windows

```
ln -s /path/to/../openmrs-module-bedmanagement/owa/app /opt/openmrs/owa/bedmanagement
```

What is the equivalent command for windows.

Comment: "windows soft link" => https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10/1020825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mklink` to the rescue, this shows you how to use it:

```
Prompt>mklink
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
            refers to.
```